How to make a emails field using QML?
In many web email services, one can put in an email and it is collapsed into its own container. I can then continue to insert more emails and the process continues. I have attached an image to showcase this: 
Can something similar be achieved Qt using QML components? I do not see how I can put anything besides text into a text area.
I attempted a solution where I move the entire text area, but that was ineffective when it came to multiline email lists.
The icon is not needed.

You won't get what you want from one component. You need to attempt with several components working together. For instance, I would start by looking at using Flow+Repeater+TextEdit. But that will only give you the text input. Then, you have to decorate it with an icon, etc. Some effort is needed.

@StephenQuan Thank you for the response. Do you think it is a good decision to constantly detect user input and use html and css to format it. That is, have the user type into a rich text box and format it as they type? Additionally, the icon is not needed. I screenshotted gmail for an example. I will append that to the question.

I am sure you could do something with HTML and CSS, however, that would be a total disregard of what you can do with QML components. If you spent a bit of time in looking at Flow+Repeater+TextEdit like I mentioned previously I'm certain you can get something to work.

This is similar to what was done in QtDesignStudio with the Expression Builder. Have a look at this video https://youtu.be/KDxnMQzgmIY?si=Qow6J1Bg9xeCmcVE&t=310 The Expression Builder is used to form the contents of an if statement similar to the recipient field of a mail client. You can freely type, when accepted it will become a "pill" that can be removed again. This was solved similar to what Stephen proposed. Have a look at the source https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/share/qtcreator/qmldesigner/connectionseditor/ExpressionBuilder.qml If you need help, just ask.

I would do such a component with states. one state for input box and one for the label

The Flow component may be used to contain the addresses entered and the current addresses being entered. You will see that the existing addresses are read-only Text component whilst the current address is editable via TextInput.
    property list<string> to: ([
        "example@example.com",
        "other_example@example.com"
    ])
    Flow {
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 10
        // To label
        Frame { background: Item { } Text { text: "To" } }
        // Existing addresses
        Repeater {
            model: to
            delegate: Frame { Text { text: modelData } }
        }
        // Current addresses
        Frame { TextInput { text: "more_emaAA" } }
    }

You can Try it Online!

Can this be reasonably adapted to allow editing the already entered emails if required?
